# Refresh token returns a value on console but returns null on ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, null, refresh, token

I got this task as an intern in a company to implement refresh token on their system. I can see that there are some codes that are already made for it (someone already tried to implement it)but it's not working.

I traced the code and found that it creates and prints the refresh token on the console but not on the ResponseEntity (returns null). I'm not used to coding in Java EE, Spring Framework, JWT Tokens or OAuth. I still have a lot of things to learn. I saw some answers that it needs to have an access type that is offline but the codes are all in PHP. I don't know how to implement it on Java with Spring Framework. So here are some of the codes...

For the Login Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> auth(@RequestBody AuthModel auth) {
        String username = auth.getUsername();
        String password = auth.getPassword();
        UserModel user = authService.authenticate(username, password);
        if (user != null) {
            final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                     new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                             auth.getUsername(),
                             auth.getPassword()
                     )
             );
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); //set current user
            final UserDetails userDetails = authService.loadUserByUsername(auth.getUsername());
            user.setOrg_id(usrService.setOrgId(user.getCompany_id()));
            return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseModel(HttpStatus.OK.value(),jwtService.getToken(userDetails),jwtService.getRefreshToken(userDetails), "Success"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

For the Services:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public String getRefreshToken(UserDetails user)
{
    System.out.println("Get Refresh Token: " + createRefreshToken(user));
    return createRefreshToken(user);
}

public String createRefreshToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
    if (userDetails.getUsername() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create JWT Token without username");
    }

    Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(userDetails.getUsername());
    claims.put("roles", Arrays.asList(userDetails.getAuthorities()));
    Date now = new Date();
    String token = Jwts.builder()
      .setClaims(claims)
      .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
      .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
      .setIssuedAt(now)
      .setExpiration(getRefreshExpirationTime())
      .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, refreshEncodedSecret)
    .compact();
    //System.out.println("Refresh Token: " + token);
    return token;
}
```

After a success login, it returns this Response.

[ResponseEntity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCKQi.png)

And for the console...

[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzp02.png)

I hope you can answer me in details. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the implementation of createRefreshToken(user)?

Comment: Added the implementation of createRefreshToken. Sorry about that.